# How to split ports in a source into separate sources in PulseAudio?

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, lxde

`pactl list sources` shows that there is a source which has multiple ports:

```
Ports:
    analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority: 8500, not available)
    analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority: 8200, available)
    analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, available)
```

I would like to split these ports into separate sources so that I can loopback and mix them together for output in a single sink using the command:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=whatever sink=whatever
```

The `module-remap-source` does not appear to be able to do what I seek, unless I'm missing something.

Without separate sources I'm stuck with manually switching the ports using the `pavucontrol` interface which only allows one port at a time to be active for a given source.

Running Debian Stretch with LXDE.

The same setup can be achieved easily in both Windows 7 and Debian Jessie with XFCE4, where the `xfce4-mixer` GUI shows separate audio sliders for each input and all I had to do was turning up the line-in and rear-mic sliders to hear both of them mixed on the default output (in that case, my headphones).

This is the result of `cat /proc/asound/pcm`:

```
00-00: ALC887-VD Analog : ALC887-VD Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-02: ALC887-VD Alt Analog : ALC887-VD Alt Analog : capture 1
01-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
01-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1
01-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1
02-00: USB Audio : USB Audio : playback 1 : capture 1
```

This is the result of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`:

https://pastebin.com/yusn4hJP

**UPDATE:**

I have since dodged this problem by purging `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol` entirely and using `qasmixer` (with `Loopback Mixing` and `Show device selection` enabled) directly on top of Alsa. This allows the same if not a greater degree of versatility than the now obsoleted `xfce4-mixer`. Other Alsa mixers which i don't like as much but are still worthy of a try are `volti` and `alsamixergui`.

Even if this solved my problem, it's however not a full answer to this question in particular, which is also about the possibility to split Pulseaudio ports into indipendent sources and how.

Comment: The question is if your soundcard has enough A/D converters to access all 3 simultanously in the first place. `arecord -L` can give hints for this. In any case, edit your question with `lspci -nn` or `lsusb` identification of your soundcards. If it's a HDA soundcard, put output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` into a pastebin and edit question with link. Even if it's possible with your hardware, the ALSA configuration will be a challenge, if it can be done at all.

Comment: Also look at `cat /proc/asound/pcm`.

Comment: @dirkt i know for certain that the soundcard has the capability to do it because i found it trivial to set up such a configuration in both win7 and jessie/xfce, but inexplicably hard in stretch/lxde which is the system i'm having trouble with. It's an HDA soundcard, Realtek ALC887-VD.

Comment: Please edit question with output of `cat /proc/asound/pcm`. If that doesn't show *three* "Analog" capture sources (the second labelled "Alt Analog", I've never seen a third), edit question with output of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` (or put it in a pastebin and give link). Please explain in detail in your question how you set it up on Jessie.

Comment: @dirkt Ok i added the info to the question, let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You only have two A/D converters (Audio Input nodes), called "ALC887-VD Analog" and "ALC887-VD Alt Analog" by ALSA. So the best you could achieve on the software side is two sources, where you'd have to switch ports manually for both (as you are doing now for a single source). That's not trivial to set up, though, you have to fiddle with profiles and path in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/`, and manually unload and load Pulseaudio modules. I played around with it on my system, and I still haven't got a satisfying configuration.

However, if your goal is "I want to loopback hardware audio inputs into hardware audio outputs (headphone)" instead of "I want multiple Pulseaudio source, so I can loopback in Pulseaudio into whatever sinks", you can just use the hardware mixers (that's probably what you did in Windows 7 and xfce4-mixer).

So use `alsamixer` or `amixer` or a similar program to control hardware loopback settings, and it should work just as before.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I would like to specify a few things however. I'm _not_ using a hardware mixer in the sense of, for example, a DJ set with actual touchable knobs, wires and all that jazz. It's fine that my motherboard can't handle 3 inputs, two is enough as actually i keep unused one of them (the front one). I can accept that doing the port splitting is hard, but at least for now i would like to keep this question open just in case somebody else can come with a full answer to that specifically. I also added an update to the bottom of my question.

Comment: What is inside the soundchip on your motherboard *is* called a "hardware mixer", even if it doesn't have actual touchable knobs, and the "knobs" are all controlled by software. All the software you are using where it "just works" (Windows 7, xfce4-mixer, qasmixer, and also alsamixer and amixer) controls those "hardware knobs" via software (the sliders you see). Pulseaudio, OTOH, is *purely* software (well, mostly, but I won't go into details), and that's why what you want doesn't work with Pulseaudio directly, or at least you can't control it from Pulseaudio.

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have found a solution to your question [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-separe-ports-into-different-devices-on-pulseaudio/55890/4). The idea is as follows:

1. Get a list of available ALSA sound cards and inputs:

   ```
   $ arecord -l
   **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
   card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
     Subdevices: 0/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
     Subdevices: 0/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   ```

   and notice the card and device numbers (in my example above there is **`card 1`** and two input devices: **`device 0`** and **`device 2`**).
2. If you do not have a per-user PulseAudio config file, make a copy:

   `cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa`
   and open your copy with simple text editor. Find the section related to static devices configuration and add the lines for your ALSA devices like this:

   ```
   ### Load audio drivers statically
   ### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
   ### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
   #load-module module-alsa-sink
   #load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
   #load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
   #load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
   #load-module module-null-sink
   #load-module module-pipe-sink

   load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,0 name="ALSAOutput"
   load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0 name="ALSASource1" source_properties=device.description="ALSASource1"
   load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,2 name="ALSASource2" source_properties=device.description="ALSASource2"


   ### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
   #.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
   #load-module module-udev-detect
   #.else
   ### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
   #load-module module-detect
   #.endif
   ```

   In these lines you have to edit the parameter `device=hw:1,0` according to your configuration. Here first number is the **card** number, and the second is the **device** number, which you must remember from the previous step.

   Please note that you also have to comment out the next section about the automatic driver loading with udev.
3. Restart PulseAudio for your user:

   ```
   $ systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
   ```

Once you have done that, in `pavucontrol` you will see a single output device and two independent input devices:

[image]

[image]

Note that the input devices in `pavucontrol` have the names we assigned to them in our config file above (the parameter `source_properties=device.description="ALSASource1"`). This is a convenient way to assign the devices distinctive names.

4. Next, to be able to use those inputs you have to actually assign the proper sources of sound to each of the ALSA inputs. For this I suggest you to start `alsamixer` in your console, choose the sound card by pressing F6, then press F4 to switch to the 'Capture' tab and assign the necessary inputs like this:

[image]

In my example I chose the `Line in` as the first input, and `Front Mic` as the second input.

You should also ensure these two capture devices are unmuted. To turn them on, just switch to the `Capture` and `Capture 1` controls using the Left/Right arrow keys and press Spacebar. You will see the red word '**CAPTURE**' appear when the device is **ON**.

So at this point you have **two ports** of a single device split into **two separate devices** in PulseAudio, and next you are free to do whatever you want with them using `pavucontrol` as usual. For example, to join the signal from these two sources, you may use [this recipe](https://askubuntu.com/a/870596/298881).

To revert all these changes, you may edit back the `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` file commenting out the new lines and uncommenting the old ones. Or you may simply delete this file. And then, restart PulseAudio again.

P.S. I believe there must be a smarter way to do this (for example, by creating a custom device profile for PulseAudio), but I am not familiar with that. Maybe someone else here could give a hint.